# How can I improve my SAS Code? It will take so much time to rune the code

Tags: sql, sas, case

How can I improve this code snippet because it will take so much time to over just 7000 items. Next step will be to run this code over 300000 lines.

Can I write another kind of case for make the code faster?

```
PROC SQL;

UPDATE GRV_Export_Dummy D
    SET 'PAYMENTROLE'n = 
                            (CASE
                                WHEN (SELECT 'H01'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' &
                                     (SELECT 'H02'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' &
                                     (SELECT 'H03'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' &
                                     (SELECT 'H04'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' &
                                     (SELECT 'H05'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' &
                                     (SELECT 'H06'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' 
                                THEN 'H/' 
                                ELSE ''
                            END)
                            ||
                            (CASE
                                WHEN (SELECT 'H01'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1' !
                                     (SELECT 'H02'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1' !
                                     (SELECT 'H03'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1' !
                                     (SELECT 'H04'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1' !
                                     (SELECT 'H05'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1' !
                                     (SELECT 'H06'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) <> '1'
                                THEN
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H01'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H1/' ELSE '' END) ||
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H02'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H2/' ELSE '' END) ||
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H03'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H3/' ELSE '' END) ||
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H04'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H4/' ELSE '' END) ||
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H05'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H5/' ELSE '' END) ||
                                    (CASE WHEN (SELECT 'H06'n FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR) = '1' THEN 'H6/' ELSE '' END) 
                                ELSE ''
                            END)
WHERE D.VTITEM IN (SELECT V.VTGONR FROM SERVER.VIEWTABLE V WHERE D.VTITEM = V.VTGONR);
QUIT;
```

EDIT 01.10.2019
here we go, some samples
This is just a short code snippet from my code, I have more cases like this.

```
OUTPUT    
SAMPLE 1 --> H1/H6
SAMPLE 2 --> H/
SAMPLE 3 --> H3/H4/H5/H6
```

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td>VTGONR</td>
<td>H01</td>
<td>H02</td>
<td>H03</td>
<td>H04</td>
<td>H05</td>
<td>H06</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6123456</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6135678</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5797897</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There may be a simpler way of doing this. Please post some sample input and output data. Edit your question and include the sample data as text. Please do not post pictures of text.

Comment: Is your table on some other database that is accessible via the `server` library?

Comment: Are you saying your SERVER.VIEWTABLE has 7,000 columns (H1 to H7000) ?  Try looking at the view source to see how VIEWTABLE is constructed, you might be able to leverage a simpler underlying data structure that is the basis for the VIEWTABLE  (It may itself be a very large source code with 7,000 case statements!)

Comment: I have add some more information to my post with samples

Comment: Please answer @samkart's above question. Does data originate from external source?

Comment: Yes, I get this data from an other server. I make always a copy of the data because of the speed problems.

Comment: So the speed issue comes from the connection. The thing is SAS will bring in the data to its memory for every `select` statement, and you have **many** of them. Usually, it can be saved as a SAS table and then use the `select` from the SAS table instead of the `server.viewtable`. You could also try using `options dbidirectexec` but I don't think it will be of much use in your case.